# Python: Get next element from the list based on input?

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
elem_list = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I'm trying to get next element from the list based on input

```
input_val = 'c'
out_data = 'd'

input_val = 'a'
out_data = 'b'

input_val = 'd'
out_data = ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `input_val` is guaranteed to be present exactly once in the list, you can use:

```
out_data = ''
elem_index = elem_list.index(input_val)
if elem_index != len(elem_list)-1:
    out_data = elem_list[elem_index+1]
```

Here, you are first finding the index of the input in the list, and setting the output to be the value at the next index unless it is the last element, in which case you set it as the empty string.